# ASP.NET CORE controller parameters problems with multiselection datatables data binding

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, datatables

I have a table with the datatable library attached which includes pagination and every row has a checkbox where the user can select multiple products to save.

It works, I get the selected ids of the products binded to a list when sent to the Controller, BUT it would only bind those who are selected on the page it is on when sent to the Controller even if I have selected multiple other ones on other pages in the table it would only remember that page it is on, I can even see they are still selected when I go back to the other pages so the checkbox works.

So my big question is: **how do I make sure that every selected row is being bind into the controller paramter productidslist, even with pagination on in the datatable?**

Each row looks like this:

```html
<tr>
  <th><input type="checkbox" name="ProductIdsList" value="@p.ProductId" /></th>
  <td>@p.ProductName</td>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
</tr>
```

thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you please provide the code snippet for controller and jquery Datatable ?

Comment: Not really much to see, just a Controller with a List<int> productidslist parameter and a standard jquery datatable.

Comment: Have you tried this https://jsfiddle.net/gyrocode/snqw56dw/   by Michael Ryvkin at gyrocode  ful article link  https://www.gyrocode.com/articles/jquery-datatables-row-selection-using-checkboxes-and-select-extension/